# Can anyone help changing nameservers

Tags: hosting, nameserver, web

Im in a bit of a hard one here. Im trying to change the nameservers of a website I have been given. Im a web designer and have my own hosting.

A client of mine is giving me all of his clients. This one is a bit of head scratcher.

Its a service I have never heard of, I am hoping somebody has. The name of the company is bizsiteservice. After a bit of investigation, they have no website or they do but there is nothing on it.

So I tried finding where the nameservers are located, Ive found dns1.name-services.com, there is no website for them either.

So my question is how can I change nameservers with having to hunt down a registrar and nameservers that dont seem to exist.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated as I have to get this website live by the weekend.

Thank you

Comment: You should get some more info from your client. There's no way to modify name servers without the registrar.

Comment: Ok Ive got a bit more info from the client, but it is still leading me down a dead end. It turns out the company name eZot but its still not clear as to how to login and chang the name servers, lol Id cry but I think Ill just laugh instead before I crack up hahahaha Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

In reality **you can't** change a domain's name servers without interacting with the owner or the registrar somehow. If it were possible to change domain registry records without involving them then it would completely undermine the Internet ;-)

Looking at the registrar data for **name-services.com**, the domain owner has used a private registration method to hide his/her details. You can see the registrar he/she used though:

https://who.is/whois/name-services.com

If you take a look at the IP address owner info of one of name-services.com's DNS servers you might be able to find out a little more info:

https://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/98.124.196.1/

Comment: Ok Ive got a bit more info from the client, but it is still leading me down a dead end. It turns out the company name eZot but its still not clear as to how to login and chang the name servers, lol Id cry but I think Ill just laugh instead before I crack up hahahaha Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how can I change nameservers with having to hunt
>   down a registrar and nameservers that dont seem to exist.

That is exactly what you need to do. Contact the client and find out all the information you can about this domain and its registrar. You *need* to interact with the registrar to change the domain's nameservers.

Comment: Ok Ive got a bit more info from the client, but it is still leading me down a dead end. It turns out the company name eZot but its still not clear as to how to login and chang the name servers, lol Id cry but I think Ill just laugh instead before I crack up hahahaha Thanks for the reply